# How to input C array when using python embedding?

Tags: python, c

I want to use operate python function using c array variable. In case of C++, embedded python function works well. However, C case, it doesn't work. Any idea?

Here are code.

1. test1.py

```py
def array_add(x):
   return sum(x)
```

2. test_main.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <Python.h>

void CreatePyTuple(double input[], PyObject* output)
{
    output = PyTuple_New(3);
    for (int index = 0; index < 3; index++)
        PyTuple_SetItem(output,index,PyFloat_FromDouble(input[index]));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    double result, x[3];
    Py_Initialize();
    PyObject *pName, *pModule, *pDict, *pFunc, *pArgs, *pValue, *pText, *pX;
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
    PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append(\".\")");
    pName = PyUnicode_FromString((char*)"test1");
    pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
    pFunc = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule,(char*)"array_add");

    for (int it=0; it<1; it++)
    {
        x[0] = 0.1;
        x[1] = 0.125;
        x[2] = -0.5;
        CreatePyTuple(x,pX);
        pArgs = PyTuple_New(1);
        PyTuple_SetItem(pArgs,0,pX);
        printf("Check\n");
        if (pArgs == NULL)
            printf("pArgs NULL\n");
        pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pArgs);// Here!
        printf("Check\n");
        if (pValue == NULL)
            printf("pValue NULL\n");
        result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pValue);
    }
    printf("%f\n",result);
    return 0;
}
```

The problem happens bellow line.

```
pValue = PyObject_CallObject(pFunc,pArgs);
```

This line calls `Segmentation fault(core dumped)` error.

For variable `x` is `{0.1,0.125,-0.5}`, I want the result must be `-0.275`.

Comment: You check pArgs against NULL, what do you know about pFunc?

Comment: Oh, I have already checked pFunc.
pFunc is in PyCallable status. So, I think pFunc is not problem in my case.